# fade out everything but hovered link is not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I use this hover-effect, where everything but the hovered  Element fades out, you can see it in the snippet below.

Its working in Firefox (Version 66.0.3 ) but not in Chrome (Version 73.0.3683.103). I also tried Microsoft Edge, it works there aswell.

I tried adding  "-webkit-" because I read, that this could fix the problem, but it didn´t. 
Anybody an idea how to achieve this hover-effect in Chrome?

```css
.links{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Hover Effect */
.hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hover > * {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 100ms linear 100ms;
}

.hover:hover > * {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.hover > *:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0ms, 0ms;
}
```

**EDIT:** 
It works in Chrome, if I remove the links (in my case references to other pages of the website).

Working in Chrome:

```css
.links {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Hover Effect */

.hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hover>* {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 100ms linear 100ms;
}

.hover:hover>* {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.hover>*:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0ms, 0ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <div class="hover">
    <div class="linkNav">1</div>
    <div class="linkNav">2</div>
    <div class="linkNav">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not Working in Chrome:

```css
.links {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Hover Effect */

.hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hover>* {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 100ms linear 100ms;
}

.hover:hover>* {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.hover>*:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0ms, 0ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <div class="hover">
    <a href="1.html">
      <div class="linkNav">1</div>
    </a>
    <a href="2.html">
      <div class="linkNav">2</div>
    </a>
    <a href="3.html">
      <div class="linkNav">3</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine in Chrome for me. Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Works fine in Chrome for me as well.

Comment: Yep, works on chrome

Comment: I edited my Question, cause without links it works fine for me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(N.b. I have updated this answer after noting the problem with the HTML).

I simplified your CSS to try and isolate the problem (I removed the visibility properties that aren't doing anything as well as the `> *` selectors)

It's unsurprising there is unpredictable behaviour in this case because strictly speaking you shouldn't be putting a block level element such as `<div>` inside an `<a>` element.

It seems that, in this case of malformed HTML, Chrome won't recognise the opacity value of the anchor (`<a>`) tag unless I do something like set it to `display: block` or `display:inline-block`. FireFox, Edge and IE do recognise the opacity regardless.

The best solution would be to fix your HTML so that the block level elements wrap the inline elements properly.

```css
.links {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.hover:hover a {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.hover a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="links hover">
  <div class="linkNav"><a href="1.html">1</a></div>
  <div class="linkNav"><a href="2.html">2</a></div>
  <div class="linkNav"><a href="3.html">3</a></div>
</div>
```

I would recommend fixing it like this but if for some reason you can't fix the HTM a workaround is to set the `display` property on your anchor tags. Like so:

```css
.links {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.links a {
  display:block;
}

.hover:hover a {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.hover a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="links hover">
    <a href="1.html"><div class="linkNav">1</div></a>
    <a href="2.html"><div class="linkNav">2</div></a>
    <a href="3.html"><div class="linkNav">3</div></a>
  </div>
```

Or else an alternative solution is you could simply target an alternative element, such as the inner `div` instead of the `a` tag.

JSFiddle links for the different workaround solutions and the original CVE that demonstrates the issue (useful for testing in different browsers):

[Solution by setting `display block`](https://jsfiddle.net/Chipmo/a3nz15bw/)

[Solution by changing selector to target inner div](https://jsfiddle.net/Chipmo/r1sx6ywq/)

[Original CVE which works in most browsers but not Chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/Chipmo/t76rjfxy/)

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected the code
the problem here was in the ordering you were adding HTML

The a tag has div inside it and class on that which the selector on hover was unable to reach to.

Now see, it works fine. 
This is it I guess.
Hope it solves your problem.

```css
.links {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Hover Effect */

.hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hover>* {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 100ms linear 100ms;
}

.hover:hover>* {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.hover>*:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0ms, 0ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <div class="hover">
    <a href="1.html" class="linkNav">1</a>
    <a href="2.html" class="linkNav">2</a>
    <a href="3.html" class="linkNav">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason this works is not to do with the ordering of the HTML but because you have set `display:inline-block` on the anchor tags. For some reason Chrome ignores opacity until this is explicitly set - unlike other browsers. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @ChrisM I have updated my code and removed `display: inline-block;` and then too it is working. and you have also used the same HTML as of mine, please see the HTML of OP its different. why dont you try on that. Your answer also doesnt seem to explain the problem. You just stated that as bug. Its not a bug. Its the property div is a block element and a tag is inline.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the fact about the malformed HTML - well spotted. I have updated my answer to reflect this. Setting the `display` attribute does have an impact within Chrome, but only in the case of the malformed HTML. Behaviour is consistent when the HTML structure is fixed (as you would expect). I don't think you have said that in your explanation though. Your grammar is unclear but it sounds like you're saying it's a selector issue - it's not, rather it seems to be an inconsistency in the rendering of malformed HTML.

Comment: Yes, please excuse me for my grammar and not using an appropriate word. I was actually referring about the use of div inside a tag.